# Error: Handshake inactivity timeout while using sails-mysql on macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp, sails.js

I've seen many answers but yet I'm not able to resolve my issue.
I'm using node 6.11.2, sails-mysql to connect to mysql by Xampp on macOS Sierra.
I've also tried increasing timeout in protocol.js but nothing works.

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
at afterwards (/Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
at /Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
at Handshake.onConnect (/Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:54:9)
at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
at /Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:399:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at /Users/shubham/VSCode/hirexl/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:13
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

This is my connections.js code

```
module.exports.connections = {
localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
MysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'hirexl_test_db',
    user: 'root',
    password:''
},
MysqlTestServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'hirexl_test_db',
    user: 'root',
    password:''
}
};
```

[image]

[connections online image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBN2d.png)

[image]

[localhost online image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYKUl.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: please make sure, your mysql server is running.

Comment: I've checked and found that mysql server is running.

Comment: Can you put up your connections.js code?

Comment: @Glen I've put up connections.js code

Comment: @RaghavGarg mysql server is runningg